# deep neural network model stops learning after one epoch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, unsupervised-learning

I am training a unsupervised NN model and for some reason, after exactly one epoch (80 steps), model stops learning.
[image]]
Do you have any idea why it might happen and what should I do to prevent it?

This is more info about my NN:
I have a deep NN that tries to solve an optimization problem. My loss function is customized and it is my objective function in the optimization problem.
So if my optimization problems is `min f(x) ==> loss`, now in my DNN `loss = f(x)`. I have 64 input, 64 output, 3 layers in between :

```
self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
self.relu1 = nn.LeakyReLU()
self.BN1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size)
```

and last layer is:

```
self.l5 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
self.tan5 = nn.Tanh()
self.BN5 = nn.BatchNorm1d(output_size)
```

to scale my network.
with more layers and nodes(doubles: 8 layers each 200 nodes), I can get a little more progress toward lower error, but again after 100 steps training error becomes flat!

[image]

Comment: Please say what kind of unsupervised you're training to get more help, for example, the reinforcement model? It's better if you tell more about your hyperparameter, model-depth, your problem, and the algorithm you chose.

Comment: Hi Toby, thanks for your comment. I updated my post.